# SEO - Submitting Search results page URLs of the website with parameters ... Good or duplicate content?

Tags: seo

I have 100 dance classes offered by different people on the page x.com/dance-classes.

Each page only lists 20, so you navigate through 5 pages to see "ALL" the dance classes.

**x.com/dance-classes**

(with a Title, some content describing the results that are displayed on the page and then the results. Results are "ALL DANCE CLASSES" targeting keywords like "Dance classes")

**user searches for dance classes for kids/adults from google**

**x.com/dance-classes?for=kids**

(with a different title, results that are may/maynot have been on the /dance-classes page, results are for "ALL DANCE CLASSES FOR KIDS")

**http://x.com/dance-classes?for=adults**
(with a different title, results that are may/maynot have been on the /dance-classes page, results are for "ALL DANCE CLASSES FOR ADULTS")

Duplicate content?

I want google to index all three URLs as they specifically aim at different sets of keywords. So, rel=canonical is not an option.

This blog by Matt Cutts talks about something relevant to my case. Should i be worried?

https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO ist not really related to GA and the question is not code-related at all; I suggest to ask this as the webmasters SO site.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I posted this question after searching through all SEO-related questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x.com/x?=x` is not friendly for SEO. It would be better to change your URLs to this type:

```
x.com/dance-classes/kids , x.com/dance-classes/adults
```

Or you can use jQuery and anchor text.

For example:

```
x.com/dance-classes#Adults , x.com/dance-classes#kids
```

In the first type, you can set a focus keyword for any page, but I don't know about jQuery and anchor text.

Comment: I understand folder-like structure (can't recall any proper name) as you suggested is better than get parameters. And that is how my website is designed. However, get parameters are used to manage sorting of the search results. For example, /dance-classes list ALL dance classes. Now, using GET like /dance-classes?for=Adults, my code knows to display all dance classes for adults. I cannot use folder like structure here as folders are designed to take category names.

For Example, dance-classes/arabic/belly-dance?for=adults
This will list all belly dances for adults.

Comment: In Wordpress, Joomla and ... there is another type of category called tags ! You can use folders like category and tags ! Tags will show arabic and ... for adult , Category will show adult, kids and ... for arabic.